# How to pass multiple values with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm looking to pass multiple values with ajax.

My Code:

```
$(".ajax-button").change(function(event){

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:'{{action("WebshopController@refreshCheckout")}}' ,
            data: {
                frame: $('input.frame:checked').val(),
                color: $('input.color:checked').val()
            },
            method: 'GET'
        }).done(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

As you can see im trying to send a frame and a color:

```
data: {
                frame: $('input.frame:checked').val(),
                color: $('input.color:checked').val()
            },
```

However it does not combine these 2, when I click the checkbox for frame it only sends the frame: and when I click checkbox for color is only sends the color. as seen in the printscreen below.

[image]

I want it to build the URL like: 
refreshCheckout?color=Silver&frame=h35

How do I achieve this?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the HTML too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590424/6854385) should be the accepted one.

Comment: Allright, now it works. but now it doesn't see which value is check for which i used the :checked selector

Comment: You normally check it before you specify the values for the ajax data. So on this one you would check if they are set and then for example get the value in two separated steps (`var`).

Comment: Allright i think i have to figure out a different way to check which value is checked. atleast the request is working now. thanks for that. i'll approve your answer.

Comment: makes no difference if you assign to variable first or not , nothing wrong with op approach to passing value to object.

Comment: now you are checking `if($(selector))` which will always be truthy...an object is returned regardless of matching elements or not. Won't work that way

Comment: no it won't..a jQuery object doesn't have a `checked` property. Not to mention that the variables are declared inside `if()` so if one or other isn't checked will throw undefined error when unknown variable passed to object

Comment: This will always return the same values (the first two for each type). I included an answer with code and link to fiddle to illustrate this.

Answer (score 2):

If a value is undefined...jQuery won't include that property. You can't get a value from a selector that doesn't exist (not checked)

You probably want to make sure you have both before submitting:

```
$(".ajax-button").change(function(event) {

  var $frameInput = $('input.frame:checked'),
    $colorInput = $('input.color:checked');

  if (!($frameInput.length && $colorInput.length)) {

    alert('Need both color and frame');

  } else {

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{action("WebshopController@refreshCheckout")}}',
      data: {
        frame: $frameInput.val(),
        color: $colorInput.val()
      },
      method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also send data like

```
$(".ajax-button").change(function(event){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url:'{{action("WebshopController@refreshCheckout")}}/?frame=$("input.frame:checked").val()&color=$("input.color:checked").val()' ,
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: this won't evaluate `$("input.frame:checked").val()` inside a string... you have to concatenate to do that

Answer (score 0):

I suppose following expressions return nothing

```
frame: $('input.frame:checked').val(),
                color: $('input.color:checked').val()
```

Check it before the request.
It will work if you pass some data there

```
data: {
                frame: 'foo',
                color: 'bar'
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your HTML code, so it's hard to tell what exactly is broken. However, simply to illustrate that the current accepted answer is probably not what you are looking for and that your code is correct except that you are likely not triggering the event when you really want to (i.e. when both fields are set) as suggested in the answer by charlietfl.

https://jsfiddle.net/b1g1pmnp/

HTML:

```
  <p>
  Color
  </p>
  <input type="radio" class="color" value="red" name="color">
  red
  <input type="radio" class="color" value="orange" name="color">
  orange
  <input type="radio" class="color" value="purple" name="color">
  purple
  <input type="radio" class="color" value="green" name="color">
  green

  <p>
  Frame
  </p>
  <input type="radio" class="frame" value="silver" name="frame">
  silver
  <input type="radio" class="frame" value="gold" name="frame">
  gold
  <input type="radio" class="frame" value="tan" name="frame">
  tan
  <input type="radio" class="frame" value="black" name="frame">
  black

  <p><button class="ajax-button">Button</button></p>
```

JS:

```
    $(".ajax-button").click(function(event) {
     // OP code         
     var color = $('input.color:checked').val();
     var frame = $('input.frame:checked').val();

     console.log("Current OP Code Results: ");
     console.log(color);
     console.log(frame);

     // Accepted code
      var data1 = $('input.color').val();
      var data2 = $('input.frame').val();

      console.log("Current Accepted Answer Results: ");
      console.log(data1);
      console.log(data2);

      return false;
    });
```

You can play around with that and see what you get for various cases.